# ExtJS 4.2 editable combo strange behaviour

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have an `editable combo` like this:

```
xtype : 'combo',
value : '',
queryMode : 'local',
displayField : 'label',
valueField : 'value',
store : someStore,
allowBlank : false,
disabled : true,
typeAhead : true,
listeners : {
    beforequery : function(record) {
        record.query = new RegExp(record.query, 'i');
        record.forceAll = true;
    }
}
```

This combo is part of a form, and the strange behaviour is this:

1. If I type some text, the combo filters the results perfect, and I can select any result after type filtering. And when I press a button to submit the form, in some point in a controller I use `combo.findRecord` to get extra data of the selected item in the combo, process that extra data and submit the form with no problem.
2. Same case than first, I type some text, the combo filters and I select an option, but if I select a part/all text(click and move mouse/double click mouse on text) and press the key combination ctrl+c (copy), and press the submit button, the `combo.findRecord` returns false, and the only difference between case 1 and 2 is that I copied (not cut) some part of the text of the selected item.

Any idea why this happens? I have googled it but haven´t find any clue about this.

Comment: Is it possible you have a listener somewhere for special keys? That is changing the selected value?

Comment: No, I only have a `select` listener for the combo in `this.control...` in a controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `new RegExp(record.query, 'i')`, because when you do `ctrl+c` on an editable combo, it goes through the listener before query, and sometimes, the value of the combo contains characters that are used in regular expressions configurations like `(`,`)` or `.`.

So the solution is to scape the string to do the search:

```
var string= record.query;
string = string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');//This line scapes all special characters
record.query = new RegExp(string,'gi')
record.forceAll = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding **forceSelection** config to the combo and share your results.

Regards,
Sandeep R